# Find out if child changeset is being created or updated in elixir phoenix

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I have a nested model which I'm creating or updating. You can think of it as a post with multiple comments, only that in this case it's a device which has multiple alarms. To show the correct form with the correct action I'm using the following code in my parent (device) template:

```
<%= if @alarm.data.id do %>
        <%= render AppWeb.AlarmView, "form.html", changeset: @alarm, action: Routes.device_alarm_path(@conn, :update,
        @device, @alarm.data.id), message: @last_message %>
 <% else %>
        <%= render AppWeb.AlarmView, "form.html", changeset: @alarm, action: Routes.device_alarm_path(@conn, :create,
        @device), message: @last_message %>
<% end %>
```

`@data` is in both cases a changeset.

This check of the `@alarm.data.id` seems unclean. `@alarm.data` is never nil, so I'm not getting runtime errors, but still... How am I expected to handle this?

Comment: There is an `action` field [docs](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Changeset.html#module-changeset-actions) that holds the current operation (insert/update). Could that be of any help?

Comment: That action is always empty. I think the reason for that is that I'm looking at the changeset before it's updated or created. Thanks for the idea though.

Comment: Upon second thought: Do you mean I should set that action manually in the controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could handle this outside of your template, in your controller for example using the [Ecto.Repo.insert_or_update/2](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Repo.html#c:insert_or_update/2) method. It uses the `:state` field of the `Ecto.Schema.Metadata` for your changeset to determine whether the alarm `schema` has already been persisted or not.

So, your template would simply be:

```
<%= render AppWeb.AlarmView, "form.html", changeset: @alarm, action: Routes.device_alarm_path(@conn, :create_or_update, @device), message: @last_message %>
```

Then, in your Controller you'd have this function:

```
def create_or_update(conn, %{"alarm" => alarm}) do
  case Repo.insert_or_update(alarm) do
    {:ok, alarm} -> ... 
    {:error, changeset} -> ...
  end
end
```